# Como obtener una entrada de datos sin tener que usar <ENTER> usando C

Tags: c

~ Estoy trabajando en un proyecto en `C` y necesito obtener una entrada de datos sin usar el salto de linea, de modo que de alguna manera pueda acceder directamente al `stdin`. La idea es implementar esto para la entrada de datos en un juego.

Comment: Tu *else* solo afecta al último *if*,  lo del enter no es problema. Si pones 9, "funciona". Mira cómo se hacen los *if- else* encadenados o, aún mejor, pon la condición cómo "mayor o igual a 0 y mejor o igual a 9". Otra opción sería un *switch*.

Comment: La función [getchar()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getchar/) no recibe argumentos, ni idea como te funcionó ese código.

Comment: Y ahora que lo veo, la variable que aparece en getchar no es la misma que usas en los if

Comment: Para un juego. ¿De consola? ¿Algún sistema operativo y/o compilador en particular?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El enter no afecta para nada, para nada.

Lo que sucede es que las comparaciones que haces son erróneas, no sé qué librería de C utilices (usualmente `getchar` no recibe ningún parámetro), pero seguramente `getchar` regresa un `char`, de ahí el nombre de la función. Y lo que estás comparando es un número con un caracter, lo cual te da el comportamiento "no deseado".

Debes de comparar caracteres con caracteres, números con números. El compilador no muestra ningún error porque técnicamente los caracteres se guardan como números, en el caso de C, se guardan con el valor ASCII correspondiente.

Al hacer la comparación `string1[k] == 9` estás comparando el código ASCII del caracter `string1[k]` con el número `9`.

Además, como señala SJuan76, el else solo afecta al último `if`.

Debes leer y parsear el caracter para que lo obtengas como un número, para ello puedes hacer uso de funciones como [`stoi`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/converting-strings-numbers-cc/)  (**s**tring **to** **i**nt), o en general de las funciones `sto*` o `strto*`.

Te dejo un ejemplo

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    printf("Introduce un número: ");
    char string[2];
    string[0] = getchar();
    if (string[0] == '9') // comparando el valor ASCII
        printf("Ingresaste el número 9\n");
    if (strtol(string, NULL, 10) == 9) // comparando el número
        printf("Ingresaste el número 9\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Obviamente en el caso de `strol` hay que agregar las validaciones correspondientes.

Comment: -Ok en resumidas cuentas... Lo que esta pasando es primero que el condicional esta mal implementado y por otro lado esta el tema de los caracteres parte que no termino de entender, se supone que los numeros tambien son carcateres...

Comment: Por otro lado esta el tema de el getchar () que ciertamente no deberia de recibir parametros, de hecho el compilador me sugeria que la sintaxis correcta es getchar(void), es raro que funcione, recurri a el como una medida desesperada, tambien habia probado antes con switch, solo que no lo puse en el comentario, el problema debe estar en mi percepcion de caracter por eso necesito que alguien me explique... 1- Cuando se compara un caracter con un numero, no se supone que se estaria comparando el codigo ascii del caracter con el numero, mas o menos parecido a un strcomp?.

Comment: @Santiax Efectivamente, los códigos ASCII son simple números, la diferencia radica en como lo toma el compilador. Cuando el compilador vea un `'9'`, convertirá el caracter a su respectivo código [ASCII](https://elcodigoascii.com.ar/codigos-ascii/numero-nueve-9-codigo-ascii-57.html), en este caso sería un `57`. Sabiendo esto, si estás comparando numeros, lo que pasa es que **son diferentes numeros**. En tu ejemplo, si yo ingreso el caracter `9`, es equivalente a `57`, por ende, `57` es diferente a `9`, así que la **condición nunca se va cumplir.**

Comment: Así es @Santiax, lo que dice MrDave1999 es totalmente cierto. Te recomiendo la lectura de [esta](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/DataRepresentation.html#zz-5.) página que contiene más información respecto a cómo son almacenados y representados los caracteres.